# Using AWS SDK with web workers

Tags: javascript, cordova, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ionic-framework

Total noob on ionic/cordova/angular here. Started last week, so I am struggling here. I am trying to upload files from an app (on iOS), which was created using Ionic and Cordova. The files are images and thus are very big. I want to upload these images in a background worker thread. Thus comes the need for web workers.

The images have to be uploaded to Amazon S3. I have the following code in my worker javascript file.

```
onmessage = function(e) {
  importScripts("aws-sdk.min.js");
  console.log("Doing work");
  self.AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';  //Error here. config is not defined :(
  self.AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'XXX', secretAccessKey: 'ABCD'});
  //More AWS stuff
  postMessage("DONE");
}
```

My main javascript file is all fine, because I tried it out with non-AWS configurations (plain old `console.log("stuff here"))` and it works all well. It starts failing as soon as I try to do anything with the AWS SDK. Also, the `aws-sdk.min.js` is being imported correctly (atleast Chrome shows no error on the console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, this seems to be solving my problems http://www.jefferydurand.com/amazon/web/services/worker/2015/05/08/amazon-javascript-sdk-web-worker.html

Interestingly, it didn't work with aws-sdk-2.2.3 but worked with the one shown in the example.

From the website:

```
  // this was the trick I needed to get the aws sdk to load.
  // web workers don't have a 'window' object but the library assumes 
  // there is a window object
  window = {};
  importScripts('https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.27.min.js');

  // initialize our dynamodb table and get it ready to accept values
  window.AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXX', secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXJJJJXXXXX'});
  window.AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
  var table = new window.AWS.DynamoDB({params: {TableName: 'song_player_metrics'}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before from a web page. That being said, I hear it is a really bad practice to expose your secret key to the public. I think most people have a server or lambda instance that signs the upload. However, it is fine for prototyping.

Anyway this code worked for me.

```
var accessKeyId = "public key here"
var secretAccessKey =  "secret key here" // secret key. This should be hidden. Maybe on a server or lambda instance. 
var bucketName = "my-new-bucket"
var region = "us-west-2"
//make bucket
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: accessKeyId, secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey})
AWS.config.region = region
var bucket = new AWS.S3({
  params: {
    Bucket: bucketName
  }
})
// upload something into bucket
//    note: you need to define a callbackFunction
bucket.putObject({
  Key: "test.txt,
  Body: "hello world. this is just a test."
}, callbackFunction)
```

This example uploaded a text file but you can also upload a Blob for an image.

Comment: My question is "How to use AWS with Webworkers" and not "How to use AWS". For the secret key usage part, you should use Cognito